# org.jibx: maven-jibx-plugin:1.2.1 - Error reading path

Tags: apache, maven, plugins, bind, jibx

I am trying to execute a goal using maven-jibx-plugin version 1.2.1, but I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.2.1:bind (default) on project XoXcertExIm: Error loading class java.lang.CharSequence: Error reading
```

path java/lang/CharSequence.class for class java.lang.CharSequence -> [Help 1]

I am using Maven 3.2.5, Java versions 1.8.0_11, and windows 7 as the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue on Jibx to support Java 8 see [Issue here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JIBX-515)
There is a Workaround in this [comment](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JIBX-515?focusedCommentId=353453&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-353453) that you can try.

Comment: I changed around my plugin and repository configurations and the issue was resolved, Thanks for your help!

Comment: @amdalal Links are broken. It is better to extract relevant section and include it in your answer.

Comment: This is supposedly fixed here in jibx-maven-plugin version 1.3.1: https://github.com/jibx/jibx/issues/3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem...

Workaround was as easy as include newer "bcel" dependency to the plugin "maven-jibx-plugin":

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Workaround to avoid error compiling with JDK 1.8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
            <version>6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You should include a new Maven repository definition in your "settings.xml" to get the new dependency:

```
<repository>
    <id>apache-snapshots-repo</id>
    <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
```

Regards